# Optimising a React Map function causing page lag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, map-function

I am building a slideshow banner in react and am using a map function to iterate through all of the images in the state data and choose the appropriate animation to either show or hide depending on index.

Only problem is that at higher display resolutions there is a substantial amount of lag.

I am pretty sure that this is to do with react having to re-render multiple elements so I am just wondering if there is a bettter solution which I could take advantage of?

FYI is there a better alternative to using string concatenation like I have done below. I'm relatively new to react and for me it makes sense to do it like this.

Please see the map function below

```
           {this.state.images.map((v,i)=>{

                let opacity = 0;
                let wrapperClass = "SlideShowBanner parallax";
                let backgroundClasses = "SlideShowBanner__backgroundIMG";
                let innerIMGClass = "SlideShowBanner__container__innerIMG";
                let textWrapper = "SlideShowBanner__container__content__text";
                let zIndex;

                if(this.loaded){
                    if (i !== this.state.slideIndex) {
                        zIndex = 1;
                        innerIMGClass += " outAnim";
                        backgroundClasses += " outAnim"
                        wrapperClass += " hide";
                        textWrapper += " outAnim";
                    }
                    else {
                        zIndex = 0;
                        innerIMGClass += " inAnim";
                        backgroundClasses += " inAnim";
                        textWrapper += " inAnim";
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if (i !== this.state.slideIndex){
                        // Prevent the animation from being seen 
                        // but still present to hide slides
                        zIndex = -1;
                        innerIMGClass += " outAnim";
                        backgroundClasses += " outAnim"
                        wrapperClass += " hide";
                        textWrapper += " outAnim";
                    }
                }

                return(
                    <div
                        className={wrapperClass}
                        style={{
                            zIndex
                        }}
                        key={i}
                    >

                        <div 
                            className={backgroundClasses}
                            style={{
                                backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.images[i]})`,
                                backgroundSize: 'cover'
                            }}
                        ></div>

                        {/* Circle component */}

                        <div className="SlideShowBanner__container">

                            {/* Inner Background IMG */}
                            <div
                                className={innerIMGClass}
                                style={{backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.images[i]})`,}}
                                // ref={this.innerIMG}
                            ></div>

                            {/* RHS Content */}
                            <div className="SlideShowBanner__container__content">
                                <div className={textWrapper}>
                                    <div className="header">{`${this.state.text[i].header}`}</div>
                                    <div className="footnote">{`${this.state.text[i].para}`}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
```

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox or something where try and see the current status of things?

Comment: @0xc14m1z Sure heres a jsfiddle of the React component and SCSS - https://jsfiddle.net/cavan21/pbyLc2fo/2/